Type 'WritableDraft<User> | null' is not assignable to type 'User | null'
I've been facing this problem for a long time in my repo and I can't figure out what it's due to:
`
Failed to compile.

src/store/documents/documents.slice.ts
TypeScript error in src/store/documents/documents.slice.ts(30,35):
Type '{ areDocumentsLoading: true; shouldFetchDocuments: false; list: WritableDraft<ContractDocument>[]; isDocDownloadLoading: boolean; hasDocumentsLoadingError: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IDocumentsState'.
  Types of property 'list' are incompatible.
    Type 'WritableDraft<ContractDocument>[]' is not assignable to type 'ContractDocument[]'.
      Type 'WritableDraft<ContractDocument>' is not assignable to type 'ContractDocument'.
        Types of property 'user' are incompatible.
          Type 'WritableDraft<User> | null' is not assignable to type 'User | null'.  TS2322

    28 |     builder.addCase(
    29 |       fetchDocuments.pending,
  > 30 |       (state): IDocumentsState => ({
       |                                   ^
    31 |         ...state,
    32 |         areDocumentsLoading: true,
    33 |         shouldFetchDocuments: false

The error does not appear at build time or when the app is first launched. It ONLY appears when I make a modification, so I have to Ctrl+C and relaunch the app to see my changes without this error.
Here is my typescript version : 4.9.5 , reduxjs/toolkit : 1.9.0.
My code looks perfectly good on this side, I think a version of redux/typescript block me.
Here is ContractDocument class :
export default class ContractDocument extends CommonEntity {
    user: User | null;
    instance: ContractInstance | null;
    tasks: Task[];
    filename: string;
    s3_path: string;
    status: number;
    archived: number;
    private: number;
    displayed: boolean;
    hideDownloadPage: boolean;
    needsLawyerApproval: boolean;
    documentIndex: number;
    contractData: ContractData | null;
    expiresAt?: Date;
}

Here is IDocumentState :
const initialState: IDocumentsState = {
  list: [],
  areDocumentsLoading: false,
  isDocDownloadLoading: false,
  hasDocumentsLoadingError: false,
  shouldFetchDocuments: false
}

And finally, the error append here :
    builder.addCase(
      fetchDocuments.pending,
      (state): IDocumentsState => ({
        ...state,
        areDocumentsLoading: true,
        shouldFetchDocuments: false
      })
    )

Thank you for any information you may have on this subject.
I've tried changing the version of typescript, as well as reduxjs/toolkit.

A writeabledraft is something where you must  mutate your data so instead of destructuring you should assign the value directly to it. (draft) =>{ draft.value ="some-value"} instead of draft=> ({...draft,value:"some-value"}). This would also be ok (draft)=>{ draft = {...draft,value:"some-value"} }.
But you have to mutate it and you should never return a value from the function.
